# DateTimePicker BindingSource NULL if not manually changed

Tags: c#, winforms, datetimepicker, bindingsource, click

I have a problem with DateTimePicker and bindingsource.

When I add a new record without change Date from DateTimePicker the bindingsource set the date as null therefore problem occurs in my database

The databinding code is:

```
this.dateDateTimePicker.DataBindings.Add(
    new System.Windows.Forms.Binding("Value", 
         this.storeBindingSource, 
         "date", 
         true));
```

If a choose a date from DateTimePicker all works fine!

what is the problem and how could I fix it

Comment: You will probably need to provide some code or more of an explanation of how you set things up. The winforms datetimepicker (if that is what you use - you need to specify the platform) defaults to now()

Comment: the datetimepicker has the default value (now()) and shows the correct date. the poblem occurs when save a new record

Comment: There is no more information about that. I used the auto-generate code of c#.net through studio.net tools datasource and by drag & drop of table (in details mode) into form

Comment: There is more information - we aren't mind readers and as it stands what you have shown works. What is the datasource of the storeBindingSource? Have you checked the value of that source to see if it is null or now?

Answer (score 0):

Add `<datetimepicker>.Value = DateTime.Now;` at form load and check `<datetimepicker>.Value` via messabebox before insertion.

Comment: The DateTimePicker has alread value, even if I add <datetimepicker>.Value = DateTime.Now; on load. I think the problem is into  bindingsource

Comment: this.dateDateTimePicker.DataBindings.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.Binding("Value", this.storeBindingSource, "date", true));